# Why does MySQL permit non-exact matches in SELECT queries?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, security

Here's the story. I'm testing doing some security testing (using zaproxy) of a Laravel (PHP framework) application running with a MySQL database as the primary store for data.

Zaproxy is reporting a possible SQL injection for a POST request URL with the following payload:

```
id[]=3-2&enabled[]=on
```

Basically, it's an AJAX request to turn on/turn off a particular feature in a list. Zaproxy is fuzzing the request: where the `id` value is `3-2`, there should be an integer - the `id` of the item to update.

The problem is that this request is working. It should fail, but the code is actually updating the item where `id = 3`.

I'm doing things the way I'm supposed to: the model is retrieved using Eloquent's `Model::find($id)` method, passing in the `id` value from the request (which, after a bit of investigation, was determined to be the string "3-2"). AFAIK, the Eloquent library **should** be executing the query by binding the ID value to a parameter.

I tried executing the query using Laravel's `DB` class with the following code:

```
$result = DB::select("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=?;", array("3-2"));
```

and got the row for `id = 3`.

Then I tried executing the following query against my MySQL database:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='3-2';
```

and it **did** retrieve the row where `id = 3`. I also tried it with another value: "3abc". It looks like **any** value prefixed with a number will retrieve a row.

So ultimately, this appears to be a problem with MySQL. As far as I'm concerned, if I ask for a row where `id = '3-2'` and there is no row with that exact ID value, then I want it to return an empty set of results.

I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to change this behaviour? It appears to be at the level of the database server, so is there anything in the database server configuration to prevent this kind of thing?
2. This looks like a serious security issue to me. Zaproxy is able to inject some arbitrary value and make changes to my database. Admittedly, this is a fairly minor issue for my application, and the (probably) only values that would work will be values prefixed with a number, but still...

Comment: maybe its larvel, but out of the box `WHERE id='3'` will NOT select  "3abc"

Comment: The problem is that MySQL is casting the string "3-2" to a number "3"; to avoid this you can either screen your inputs or could make the query `WHERE CAST(id AS CHAR) = ?`

Comment: I think that type-juggling is the answer to your issue. Since the string starts with a 3, MySQL is basically saying well we have an "int" so ignore the rest.

Comment: @Dagon, his problem is that `WHERE id='3abc'` WILL select "3"

Comment: @Uueerdo ah sorry so long i read it backwards ;-)

Comment: You can easily reproduce this: `echo (int) "3-2";` will output `3`. It seems like expected behavior to me.

Comment: Thanks guys. Yes, it's clearly MySQL's type-juggling that is causing this. I'm not in a position to rewrite the query, since I'm using the Eloquent ORM library for my models. I *could* check values using PHP's `is_numeric` function, but that means a lot of rewriting (and I don't think I should have to, if MySQL just behaved itself).

Comment: [Same question on Security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/88583/539)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id= ? AND ? REGEXP "^[0-9]$";
```

This will be faster than what I suggested in the comments above.
Edit: Ah, I see you can't change the query. Then it is confirmed, you must sanitize the inputs in code. Another ***very poor and dirty*** option, if you are in an odd situation where you can't change query but can change database, is to change the id field to [VAR]CHAR.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is due to MySQL automatically converting your strings into numbers when comparing against a numeric data type.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/type-conversion.html

> mysql> SELECT 1 > '6x';
>
> -> 0
>
> mysql> SELECT 7 > '6x';
>
> -> 1
>
> mysql> SELECT 0 > 'x6';
>
> -> 0
>
> mysql> SELECT 0 = 'x6';
>
> -> 1

You want to really just put armor around MySQL to prevent such a string from being compared. Maybe switch to a different SQL server.

Comment: I just looked into that for this question, it appears strict mode only works for INSERT (and UPDATE).

Comment: Right, I'll take it out as it's confusing. I hate that the innodb strict mode page doesn't really say anything useful about it.

Answer (score 1):

Without re-writing a bunch of code then in all honesty the correct answer is

> This is a non-issue

Zaproxy even states that it's **possibly** a SQL injection attack, meaning that it does not know! It never said "umm yeah we deleted tables by passing x-y-and-z to your query"

```
// if this is legal and returns results
$result = DB::select("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=?;", array("3"));

// then why is it an issue for this
$result = DB::select("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=?;", array("3-2"));

// to be interpreted as
$result = DB::select("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=?;", array("3"));
```

You are parameterizing your queries so Zaproxy is off it's rocker.

Comment: It's an issue because the ORM is reading a model based on `id = '3-2'`, then making changes to that model. It is making changes to my database based on arbitrary input, which seems to me almost the definition of an SQL injection. Admittedly, in the case I have stumbled upon it's a pretty minor change and a pretty limited domain of values for which the injection works, but it's still an injection.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I wound up doing:

First, I suspect that my expectations were a little unreasonable. I was expecting that if I used parameterized queries, I wouldn't need to sanitize my inputs. This is clearly not the case. While parameterized queries eliminate some of the most pernicious SQL injection attacks, this example shows that there is still a need to examine your inputs and make sure you're getting the right stuff from the user.

So, with that said... I decided to write some code to make checking ID values easier. I added the following trait to my application:

```
trait IDValidationTrait
{
    /**
     * Check the ID value to see if it's valid
     *
     * This is an abstract function because it will be defined differently
     * for different models. Some models have IDs which are strings,
     * others have integer IDs
     */
    abstract public static function isValidID($id);

    /**
     * Check the ID value & fail (throw an exception) if it is not valid
     */
    public static function validIDOrFail($id)
    {
        ...
    }

    /**
     * Find a model only if the ID matches EXACTLY
     */
    public static function findExactID($id)
    {
        ...
    }

    /**
     * Find a model only if the ID matches EXACTLY or throw an exception 
     */
    public static function findExactIDOrFail($id)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Thus, whenever I would normally use the `find()` method on my model class to retrieve a model, instead I use either `findExactID()` or `findExactIDOrFail()`, depending on how I want to handle the error.

Thank you to everyone who commented - you helped me to focus my thinking and to understand better what was going on.